# Nodemailer OAUTH Gmail connection (Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 74.125.140.108:465)

Tags: oauth-2.0, smtp, gmail-api, nodemailer, smtp-auth

Im trying to use OAUTH 2.0 to send emails with Gmail API using Nodemailer

I have Enable the Gmail API and i have clientId, clientSecret, refreshToken and accessToken (refreshtoken and accesstoken were taken from developers.google.com/oauthplayground) because these all were needed for OAUTH to work.

i have followed every detail form (https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/#examples)
But i'm getting following error

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 74.125.140.108:465
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '74.125.140.108',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN' }
```

**But there is a catch when i use Plain username and password there is no connection timeout error because i have already enabled less secure app access form (https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) so there is no error in sending emails using plain username and password** but this is not a good approach so OAUTH is the solution

here is my code for you to check (its an express app) running in development running on http://localhost:3000

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
port: 465,
secure: true,
service: 'gmail',
auth: {
  type: 'OAuth2',
  user: 'mygmailaddress@gmail.com',
  clientId: 'clientID',
  clientSecret: 'clientSecret',
  refreshToken: 'refresh token obtained from https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground',
  accessToken: 'access token also obtained from https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground'
}
});
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'me <myemailaddress@gmail.com>',
    to: '',
    subject: 'Subject ',
    text: 'Some thing',
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response) => {
    if(error){
        console.log(error);   // Always giving Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 74.125.140.108:465
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

it not even try to login because when login fails it gives error of wrong credentials (checked with plain username and password)

*Note please don't mark this question as duplicate because i have check almost all other question and answers but nothing worked 
some people said its because of firewall setting i have check that too but didn't worked 
So whats the issue and how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Your port no is wrong for gmail. Use This Format for gmail

```
const nodeMailer = require('nodemailer');

let transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 587, false for other ports
    requireTLS: true,
    auth: {
        user: your email, 
        pass: your password, 
    },
});

let mailOptions = {
    from: 'from@gmail.com',
    to: 'to@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
    text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
       console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking to your problem i assume that when generated the OAuth credentials e.g(clienId and Clientsecret ) you did not added https://mail.google.com/ in you scope on connect screen because you would need verification form google to add these scope for the credentials

you must have added this to your scope on (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) but i'm sure you have add this to your scope on consent screen as well before generating credentials

[OAuth consent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xci9m.jpg)

as you are in Development mode and running your application on localhost so you don't have private domain and privacy policy

Adding  https://mail.google.com to your scope before generating clientId and Cliensecret will resolve your problem